# Skype status always appears offline for one user

Tags: skype, user

I have one Skype contact who always appears to be offline, even when he's online.  We've chatted regularly over Skype for years without any issues, except for the fact that he always appears to be offline to me.  He can see when I'm online, and other people can see when he's online, but I can't.

He's not trying to hide from me.  We've tried and failed to get this working on a few different occasions.

Answer (score 2):

Tonight we managed to fix this.  Here's what we did:

1. We both removed each other from our contacts.
2. He added me back as a contact.
3. I accepted his invitation, agreeing to let hem see me when I'm online.

Both of us removing each other seemed to be the key.  When only one of us removed the other, it didn't fix the issue, but when we both removed each other and then he re-added me, he finally appeared to be online.

Comment: Sounds like you may have accidentally ended up on his block list.  Just a guess.

Comment: or that that one of you may have not checked "allow contact to see me when i am online" (rough quote) box...

Answer (score 0):

The year is 2023 and I still encounter issues with some or all of my Skype contacts from time to time. Workaround to resolve this - while the Skype app is running, I simply open a browser and go to the online version of Skype at https://web.skype.com/. By doing so, I am able to observe my contacts' statuses refreshing on both the app and web versions of Skype.