# Why Skype shows online users as offline?

Tags: windows-7, skype

I run Skype 4.2 in Windows 7. I have a contact who cannot see me even I'm online. I can't see her when she becomes online. Neither of us blocked any contact. Neither of us sets status as invisible or any such settings.

Why is this happening? It happens most of the times, though not all the time.

Comment: dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/158425/skype-status-always-appears-offline-for-one-user

Comment: that's fon one particular user. i'm not sure if my case is for one user or not.